# Calculating combinations where all the elements chosen are the same.

Tags: combinations

If I have 7 red balls and 8 blue balls and have to choose 4 balls from this 15, how many possible combinations can I get where all 4 balls are red balls?

I've tried using the Combinations formulae where I'm basically selecting 4 elements from the 7 [of the red balls] and coming away with: $$\displaystyle\frac{7!}{(7-4)! 4!}$$ where there are 35 possible combinations, although this doesn't seem correct to me. Am I on the right track with this line of thinking?

Comment: This is fine. Why doesn't it seem correct?

Comment: I think I was second guessing myself to be honest. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The number of ways of selecting exactly $k$ of the $7$ red balls and $4 - k$ of the $8$ blue balls when $4$ balls are chosen is 
$$\binom{7}{k}\binom{8}{4 - k}$$
so the number of ways of selecting $4$ red balls is 
$$\binom{7}{4}\binom{8}{0} = \binom{7}{4}$$